# function won't run interactively in shinydashboard app

Tags: r, shiny

In the following shiny app, I have embedded the `annual` and `monthly` functions on line 7-15 into the `selectizeInput` placeholder on line 22.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

annual <- function(x){
  (x/lag(x, 12) - 1)*100
  
}

monthly <- function(x){
  (x/lag(x) - 1)*100
  
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                                  fluidRow(
                                           box(selectizeInput('select_calculation', 'Calculation', 
                                                              choices = c('Monthly' = monthly, 'Annual' = annual)
                                                              ), height=80,width=4,
                                               )
                                           ),
                                   fluidRow(
                                            box(plotlyOutput("chart"))
                                            )
                                  )
                      )
                     


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
  
                   chart <- tidyquant::tq_get('PCE',
                                              from = '2019-01-01',
                                              to = '2022-10-01',
                                              get = 'economic.data') %>% 
                             select(-symbol) %>%  
                             mutate_if(is.numeric, ~input$select_calculation(.)) %>% 
                             drop_na() %>% {
                             ggplot(., aes(x = date, y = price)) +
                             geom_line() 
                             } %>% 
                     ggplotly()
                   
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I call one of the formulas in the code for my chart (e.g `~annual(.)` on line 44, my app works fine.

[image]

However when I try to run this interactively using the `selectizeInput` option by amending line 44 as follows

```
 mutate_if(is.numeric, ~input$select_calculation(.)) %>%
```

I get the following error. Is there any way to call a function interactively successfully?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already wondered where you want to go with this. The issue is that `input$select_calculation` is a character not a function, i.e. to make your code work you have to `parse` the input using e.g.

```
output$chart <- renderPlotly({
    calc_method <- eval(parse(text = input$select_calculation))
    chart <- tidyquant::tq_get("PCE",
      from = "2019-01-01",
      to = "2022-10-01",
      get = "economic.data"
    ) %>%
      select(-symbol) %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ calc_method(.)) %>%
      drop_na() %>%
      {
        ggplot(., aes(x = date, y = price)) +
          geom_line()
      } %>%
      ggplotly()
  })
```

But IMHO the easier approach would be to use e.g. `switch` inside the server to switch the function used for the calculations instead of trying to pass the function via `choices`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

annual <- function(x) {
  (x / lag(x, 12) - 1) * 100
}

monthly <- function(x) {
  (x / lag(x) - 1) * 100
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(selectizeInput("select_calculation", "Calculation",
        choices = c("Monthly" = "monthly", "Annual" = "annual")
      ), height = 80, width = 4, )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(plotlyOutput("chart"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$chart <- renderPlotly({
    calc_method <- switch(input$select_calculation,
      "monthly" = monthly,
      "annual" = annual
    )

    chart <- tidyquant::tq_get("PCE",
      from = "2019-01-01",
      to = "2022-10-01",
      get = "economic.data"
    ) %>%
      select(-symbol) %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ calc_method(.)) %>%
      drop_na() %>%
      {
        ggplot(., aes(x = date, y = price)) +
          geom_line()
      } %>%
      ggplotly()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6727
```

[image]